# AngularJS - orderBy value when ng-repeat by key, value pair

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I have counted the ocurrences of each item in a set of data with countBy function in lodash, and the result is this:

```
$scope.colors= {
"Orange": 3,
"Blue": 2,
"Pink": 1,
"Red": 1,
"Black": 2,
};
```

Now I would like to display the data and order it by its value. I've tried with

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in colors | orderBy:value">
        {{key}} ({{value}})
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the orderBy filter doesn't seem to do the trick (see the plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N7RqtdzT4DQGhquQXxnJ?p=preview))

Is there any way to do it with the current data form, or is it a better way to structure the data in order to achieve the desired result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Objects have no order and can't be sorted directly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) says, orderBy expects an array as input, not an object. In general, although it's supported, I've never met a use-case where using an object with ng-repeat was a good idea.

Just transform your object into an array:

```
$scope.colors = [];
angular.forEach(occurrences, function(value, key) {
    $scope.colors.push({
        color: key,
        count: value
    });
});
```

and then use

```
<li ng-repeat="element in colors | orderBy:'count'">
    {{ element.color }} ({{ element.count }})
</li>
```

See your [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fSjledOzPqm6LzGtmCt9?p=preview).

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After multiple tries, I found a way to iterate an object and have it ordered by the key.

```
<div ng-repeat="key1 in keys(obj1) | orderBy: key1">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would instead use an array like so:

```
colors = [{color: 'red', value: 1}, {color: 'blue', value: 2}]
```

Then you can use

```
ng-repeat="color in colors | orderBy:'value'"
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DTtJzcUihvUL3pzJBIuu?p=preview)

Comment: Works fine as well. I marked the other one as correct as it shows the way to transform to array. Thanks for the insight anyway!

Answer (score 0):

different approach - for

> string from **JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataTable)**, so basically `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

Example is combination of few solutions (sorry for no references)
In AngularJs controller:

```
vm.propertyName = '\u0022Spaced Column Name\u0022';
vm.reverse = true;

vm.sortBy = function (propertyName) {
                   vm.reverse = (vm.propertyName === '\u0022' + propertyName +'\u0022') ? !vm.reverse : false;
                   vm.propertyName = '\u0022' + propertyName + '\u0022';
    };


vm.Data = JSON.parse(retValue.Data);
                    for (var i = 0; i < vm.Data.length; i++) {
                        var obj = {};
                        angular.forEach(vm.Data[i], function (value, key) {
                            obj[key] = value;

                        });
                        vm.DataArr.push(obj);
                    }
```

By `ng-if="key != 'Id'"` I'm hiding Id column with Guid
And then in html:

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.Data[0]" ng-if="key != 'Id'">
                    <button ng-click="vm.sortBy(key)">{{key}}</button>
                    <span ng-show="vm.propertyName == '\u0022'+key+'\u0022' && !vm.reverse" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
                    <span ng-show="vm.propertyName == '\u0022'+key+'\u0022'  && vm.reverse" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in vm.DataArr |orderBy:vm.propertyName:vm.reverse track by $index" ng-init="rowInd0 = $index">
                <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.Data[0]" ng-if="key != 'Id'">
                     <span>{{row[key]}}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```